# C# XmL Serialization - setting items to attribute only shows integer in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have a list full of building objects and i want so serialize it to an XML file. Basic serialization is working fine, yet turning the values into attributes for better readability failes strangely on all but the int-values.

Here is the building class i am using that should be serialized:

```
    public class building
    {
       [XmlAttribute]
       public string strName { set; get; }    //name
       [XmlAttribute]
       public int intCount { set; get; }      //count of building
       [XmlAttribute]
       public int intCost { set; get; }       //running cost of building
       [XmlAttribute]
       public string strProd { set; get; }    //product
       [XmlAttribute)]
       public string strRes1 { set; get; }    //first ressource required
       [XmlAttribute]
       public string strRes2 { set; get; }    //second ressource required
       [XmlAttribute]
       public int intTime { set; get; }       //time to build in seconds
    }
```

the XML-file outputtet, if i leave out the [XMLAttribute] tags, is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfBuilding xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <building>
    <strName>Holzfäller</strName>
    <strKind>Produktion</strKind>
    <intCost>2</intCost>
    <strProd>Holz</strProd>
    <strRes1 />
    <strRes2 />
    <intTime>105</intTime>
  </building>
```

Wich as is said is fine, just hard get an overview with well over 50 buildings in the file. The XML-File created with the above code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfBuilding xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <building intCount="0" intCost="0" intTime="0" />
  <building intCount="0" intCost="0" intTime="0" />
```

As you can see only the int values are added and even those are FALSE. All values are set to zero. Strangely enough if i update one value in my programm after creating the list, the change is reflected in the XML as well. Just the base values seem to be ignored / changed to zero.

Edit: i also tried setting the DataType like this:

```
[XmlAttribute(DataType = "string")]
```

But this also just makes the string go poof and not show up at all.

Kinda lost on this one. If i just leave the Attribute stuff out all is working fine, so i am at least sure the rest of my code is not causing any issues. But why would XMLSerializer ignore object attributes that are strings and reset all int values? How can i change this?

Sorry if this has been asked elsewhere, i fail to find the right words for google to solve my issue. Mainly because i don't understand whats happening here and don't know where to start. Documentations i find simply show what i am doing, claiming that it will work. But it does not obviously :-(

Comment: Try specifying the type of the attribute [like here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.datatype.aspx).

Comment: Already tried that, string will still simply disapear. I forgot to mention that, sorry. Edited my posting to reflect that.

Comment: If you are shooting for readability in a big way, you should remove the type prefixes from your attributes and store type information in a schema.

Answer (score 2):

Your `string`s are null so they are not written with the serialization.

Initialize your string fields to `string.Empty` in `building`'s default constructor and they will appear in the output.

I tested it with this constructor in `building`:

```
public building()
{
    strProd = "";
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfBuilding xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <building intCount="0" intCost="0" strProd="" intTime="0" />
  <building intCount="0" intCost="0" strProd="" intTime="0" />
</ArrayOfBuilding>
```

**Why is the behavior different in attributes?**

Xml is capable of displaying nullable types in elements by omitting the content. Attributes however, can not display nullables *and* differentiate from an empty string. Therefore, the attribute is omitted entirely.

Comment: I am not exactly sure if i understand you. Why are my strings null? I understand, SOME are, because some buildings don't need external ressources in my example. But most strings are not null at all. The name field is always there, just as the strProd field always has a value. Also if i use your constructor strProd will always be "", even tho it should read "Holz" for the first building. I don't want empty attribues just to see they are there... the value needs to be correct as well. With your constructor the attribute shows up tho, which is a good sign.

Comment: I cannot comment on why the strings are null without seeing the rest of your code. Strings initalise as null by default. Concerning XML: XML attributes are optional by default. Remember, the format is for data transfer, not for presentation. Removing attributes when they are null reduces the file size - a worthy goal! Arguably, you should keep your date in elements where possible.

Comment: Actually there really isn't much more code as of yet. Right now i have the XML with Elements as listed above. I am extracting from that XML and have those objects in my list. I then try to put it in another XML, exactly like the first time, just with attributes in place of elements. Guess ill just stick to elements if i don't find a solution by accident. Having it more easily readable is not a requirement. This question's goal is learning something along the line basically. Did not think this was such an issue, thought id miss something obvious only. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @Rattenmann Any time. Hope you got something from the discussion.